# Why do extensions sometimes say they need to be reloaded right after VSCode starts?

Tags: vscode-extensions, startup

Sometimes after I start or restart `VSCode` one or more extensions indicates that I need to reload.  I haven't detected any pattern in this.

Why does this happen?

Should it happen?

My interest in this is as a consumer of the extensions, not as an extension developer.

I have 2 possible explanations:

1. `VSCode` starts and then discovers and loads extension updates, which then need to be restarted.  So the pattern is random because the release of updates is random.
2. I typically have a handful of windows and projects open.  Maybe the extension startups are stomping on each other; since this is a race, it could also be random.

I am not claiming either explanation is correct, just offering theories.

I was expecting nothing would need to be restarted when I just opened the application.

Searched in the bug database, e.g. with "extension reload", but got too many hits to review all.  The first few pages didn't seem to have anything relevant.

Comment: I don't see any pattern either, but assume this is because an extension uses certain VS Code APIs or 3rd party modules, which do not allow re-use without new import (say, because of side-effects).

Comment: @MikeLischke What do you mean by re-use and in what contexts would it arise?

Comment: Many 3rd party node packages modify something when they are loaded (like setting up an environment or changing configurations), which potentially is no longer valid when installing/removing a vscode extension. So, to be on the safe side vscode must entire be reloaded, to start fresh with the init chain.